# Make changes to staged files in Magit

Tags: magit, spacemacs

IntelliJ has a nice feature in the overview of the staged area, where you can make changes to the files in the staging area while having the diff overview. In the Magit overview of staged changes I would also like to make changes. Is this possible?

How can I make changes to files in a view where I see the diff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magit does not currently allow editing diffs directly. I am considering to allow this in `v3`, but this would require significant and expensive changes, so I might end up not doing it.

Meanwhile you can very easily jump to the correct location in the file-visiting buffer by just pressing <kbd>RET</kbd>. (It might be nice if `diff-hl-mode` were enabled in that buffer.) Or you could give Magit's Ediff integration a try. To do so press <kbd>e</kbd>.

Comment: maybe the `ediff-stage` command is worth mentioning here? It's not precisely editing a diff like @erwin asked, but it does show differences while editing.

Comment: @npostavs You mean `magit-ediff-stage` I think.

Comment: Or just `RET` to visit the file at the correct position.

Comment: Awesome to get a response from the maintainer :). I will use `RET` for now. Thanks.

Comment: MaintainerS, npostavs is a maintainer too. And you are welcome.

Comment: @JeanPierre Yes, that is what I meant.